# Presenting Power Point slides in dual screen mode

Tags: wine, microsoft-office, presentation

I have Ubuntu 11.10 and Wine 1.3 1.3.28. I use my laptop for commercial presentations and it is common to attach it to a projector.
I would like to use a Presentation Mode in Power Point where in one screen (the projector) the slides are shown, and in the laptop screen beside the slide itself, there are other boxes such as time, notes, and next slides to come.
But in order to activate this mode, PowerPoint must be aware of the presence of 2 screens, which is not happening.

Does anyone know how to overcome this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This is a known bug, see http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=7416 for details.

Essentially, it's not currently possible at the moment because the functionality for detecting multiple displays is not implemented in WINE.

Answer (score 0):

[blork explains](https://askubuntu.com/a/168679/63886) that this is not supported by wine at this time. Please see his answer.

The link he cites notes that you could configure the displays such that the presentation is on the left (or top) and you can see the desktop and other open programs on the display to the right (or bottom) on the other monitor.

I don't suppose that's entirely satisfactory, but perhaps it's a help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Wine now supports multiple display mods. If there are any difficulties, try to dig in the section in system settings where you can choose how the DE behaves in a multi monitor setup, like open new windows where the current (active) window is, where the cursor is or in a specific monitor, etc.
If the problem cannot be solved, it is better to write https://bugs.winehq.org/ with help.

Comment: I also found a good [Master Bundles](https://masterbundles.com/) resource where a lot of cool items for design and presentations are collected. This resource has made my job easier, so I recommend you try it.